# Can't get value of object's property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what's going on here. I have a function that is an event handler for a WordPress plugin:

```
$.fn.almComplete = function(alm){
    console.log(alm);
    console.log(alm.finished);
}
```

The first output is this:

```
e.ajaxloadmore {AjaxLoadMore: Object, page: 0, speed: 300, proceed: false, init: false…}
AjaxLoadMore: Object
button: m.fn.init[1]
button_label: "Load More"
content: m.fn.init[1]
data: m.fn.init[2]
el: m.fn.init[1]
finished: true
init: false
lang: ""
loading: false
max_pages: 5
offset: 0
page: 0
pause: false
post_type: Array[1]
posts_per_page: 6
prefix: "alm-"
proceed: true
repeater: "default"
scroll: false
speed: 300
transition: "slide"
window: m.fn.init[1]
__proto__: Object
```

But the second output `console.log(alm.finished)` always outputs `false`, but that property is obviously not false so I don't believe I'm referencing this variable correctly.

How do I access the `alm` object's properties?

EDIT: Here is when this callback is called within the plugin's code:

```
        success: function (data) {
           alm.data = $(data); // Convert data to an object
           //console.log(alm.data.length);
           if (alm.init) {
              alm.button.text(alm.button_label);
              alm.init = false;
           }
           if (alm.data.length > 0) {
              alm.el = $('<div class="' + alm.prefix + 'reveal"/>');
              alm.el.append(alm.data);
              alm.el.hide();
              alm.content.append(alm.el);
              if (alm.transition === 'fade') { // Fade transition
                 alm.el.fadeIn(alm.speed, 'alm_easeInOutQuad', function () {
                    alm.loading = false;
                    alm.button.delay(alm.speed).removeClass('loading');
                    if (alm.data.length < alm.posts_per_page) {
                       alm.finished = true;
                       alm.button.addClass('done');
                    }
                 });
              } else { // Slide transition
                 alm.el.slideDown(alm.speed, 'alm_easeInOutQuad', function () {
                    alm.loading = false;
                    alm.button.delay(alm.speed).removeClass('loading');
                    if (alm.data.length < alm.posts_per_page) {
                       alm.finished = true;
                       alm.button.addClass('done');
                    }
                 });
              }

              if ($.isFunction($.fn.almComplete)) {
                 $.fn.almComplete(alm);
              }

           } else {
              alm.button.delay(alm.speed).removeClass('loading').addClass('done');
              alm.loading = false;
              alm.finished = true;
           }
        },
```

Also, the full js source code is here: https://github.com/dcooney/wordpress-ajax-load-more/blob/master/ajax-load-more/core/js/ajax-load-more.js

Comment: This is dumb, but try this: `for(var k in alm) console.log(k, alm[k]);` And see what's visible for you. Post the result here then

Comment: That's probably because the console shows the live representation of the object.

Comment: Ivan, yep, that shows `finished false`.

Comment: I didn't even know the js console could show a live representation of an object...

Comment: How would I go about utilizing the alm object in the state it's in when I do the `console.log(alm)`?

Comment: Vohuman, could you link me to some documentation on "live" objects? I can't find anything and really need to access the values that show up in the first log.

Comment: Show how you use this function. It seems you are having problems related to other asynchronous code

Comment: The code above is exactly how I'm using it. The callback is for an Ajax plugin for WordPress. If it finds a jQuery function with the name `almComplete` it uses it as the callback.

Comment: Looks like the `finished` property is not set to `true` at the point you are trying to access it. So where/when does it get set to that value?

Comment: showing a function declaration is not the same as showing how that function gets called within other code

Comment: Ok, thanks for sticking with me here. I updated the original question with the function that calls the callback.

Comment: @Gavin I am having the same issue. Console log shows finished as true, while alm.finished is false. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Sorry, never did figure it out.